# Self hosting 2000+ web services through WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

**I am looking for a way to expose many (2000+) similar web services through WCF.**

I am working on an enterprise application in which the business logic is packaged through classes (CQS). These classes compose all data required to perform a specific piece of business logic. I would like to find a way to expose these classes as web services through self hosting.

All these classes have just one action (execute). They all inherit from a base class and their properties differ per class. Based on an implemented interface and the properties, the correct business logic is executed. The web services should be able to provide the values for the properties and execute the action.

At most 5% of these will be used regularly. I know it's not feasible to create 2000+ service host instances. It is not a problem if these host instances are created on demand and destroyed after e.g. 10 minutes of inactivity. Ideally I would react on a request from a client and instantiate a host when needed.

**EDIT:**
From the reactions, I get the idea that what I am mostly looking for is a way to not having to register all endpoints. I believe the most feasible approach is that I listen for incoming requests myself and spin up hosts as required.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why self-hosting? Would Windows Activation Services (i.e. IIS) work for you?

Comment: I know IIS is an option, but my preference goes to self hosting. If self hosting won't work, I'll resort to IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have a master service that has a request/response architecture so you only have one web service but with many methods or request types? You could make it as a plugin architecture using MEF or something else. It could spin up things as needed and close them when not. It also keeps your network footprint small.

Comment: The problem with this is that when the client requests the WSDL, he gets a WSDL with 2000+ types in it. Ideally, I would like to have one WSDL per web service. Publicly it should look separate web services which a client application can register to per web service.

Comment: This wasn't really the answer I'm looking for, but you got me in the right direction. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you've written. You have 2000+ services which all implement a common base service contract?

Could you not then use dependency injection to serve up the correct concrete service bases on the specific interface requested?

So you provide a single host but create your own instance provider which uses the ServiceType requested to forward the request to the correct instance type.

Kinda like this [WCF DI](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/12/13/wcf-dependency-injection-behavior.aspx) or [Switchable WCF Service](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/d9263dcc-f7ed-42f3-bc96-321461be3306/changing-wcf-service-implementation-at-runtime.aspx) but not exactly.

Comment: Although this does help me a little bit, I still have the problem of registering the end points. To be able to provide services, I have to devise a way to have the end points registered somewhere, either by having them all registered explicitly or by being able to listen for incoming requests and spinning up hosts or endpoints on demand. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Would maybe a single/fewer services with a more flexible Execute method.  Maybe is accepts a DataContract that provides more details as to which underlying service can be used to service the request.

Failing that would  abus architecure be more useful?  You could have many messages and when sent to the bus any services interested in that particular type of message would act upon it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need more than one endpoint. For each of your command classes, expose a single operation:

```
[OperationContract]
void ExecuteClassACommand(ClassA command)
{
    command.Execute();
}
```

You could then automatically generate the operations each time you add or remove command classes.

Comment: The problem with this is that this would create a huge WSDL and would e.g. loose the namespace grouping of the original classes. This however still be solved by creating more than one class, but I would much rather have this layer dynamically generated instead of through interfaces for example using dynamic proxies. However I'm still wondering whether it's possible to break into the HTTP server of the self hosting WCF BasicHttpBinding and solve some of my issues that way.

Comment: So, group the 2000 classes into subsets, make each subset a service contract, then host the ten or so services. You can add the services to the ServiceHost in a loop.